# Add sections dynamically using Jinja2 templating

Tags: python-2.7, templates, jinja2

I am reading a log file and creating an html table from the data. I end up making as many tables in the html file as the data is presented for. But the table data to be displayed can vary. So how do I create n tables dynamically using Jinja2 templating ? Is it even possible using Jinja 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for loops in jinja2 templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for) to generate arbitrary numbers of HTML elements (tables, rows, or anything else). For example:

```
<table>
  {% for line in loglines %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ line.data1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ line.data2 }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```